# Changing the lock screen in xscreensaver to i3lock

Tags: arch-linux, i3, fluxbox

I am running `Arch Linux + Fluxbox`. I have installed `i3lock` but the screen won't lock automatically as the program isn't designed to do that. Now, I want to change the default lock screen in `xscreensaver` package to `i3lock`. I have no idea about how to do that. Any other alternative method that automatically locks the screen after a period of inactivity using `i3lock` would be equally accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using `xautolock`. It is specifically designed to start arbitrary programs in idle X sessions. (It is also mentioned in the `i3lock` manpage)

In order to lock your screen with `i3lock` after 10 minutes of idle time, you just have to run:

```
xautolock -locker i3lock
```

If you want to pass some arguments to `i3lock` and change the timeout to 5 minutes you can do so like this:

```
xautolock -time 5 -locker 'i3lock -e -c 007f7f'
```

You can also use the `xautolock` command to control a running `xautolock` session, for example if you started it from your `~/.i3/config`.

- Immediately lock screen:

  ```
  xautolock -locknow
  ```
- Temporarily disable locking

  ```
  xautolock -disable
  ```
- (Re-)enable locking:
      xautolock -enable
- Toggle between enabled and disabled:

  ```
  xautolock -toggle
  ```

For more information have a look at the `xautolock` manpage.

Comment: Very good use of examples in the answer.